# Should ARIA attribute aria-expanded="true" be used on traditional static menus (no JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria

The shop GanzNormal.ch has sort of a main menu containing of two items: "Produkte (Products)" and "Hersteller (Manufacturers)".

It is augmented using ARIA: `aria-haspopup` and `aria-expanded`.

I'm used to have ARIA on highly interactive JavaScript elements, but not on traditional links that do a page reload. So I think it's not ok to use those attributes for this menu, as it offers only traditional links.

I assume that the developers mainly searched for a way to convey the "selected/active" status of the items, but this isn't a proper way. I would assume the developers simply use a visually hidden text like "current item".

What do you think? Is it ok to set those ARIA attributes, or would it be better to remove them?

Live site: http://www.ganznormal.ch/index.cfm?&content=2010&navi=20&spr=de

Answer (score 0):

Those two buttons are acting as tabs (or as a radio button group), you should mark them up in that way. You can use the aria-selected="true" attribute to indicate which tab is the selected tab.

Comment: In my understanding, these are not tabs, as they don't provide any interactivity that resembles tabs (which would require some JavaScript stuff), but they are only traditional bare links.

Comment: You do not need to have the JavaScript interaction, that is just a recommendation. If you are opposed to the tabs, you could make is a radio button group, but I think tabs are more appropriate.